# Add blank option to top of select and make it the selected option in IE

Tags: jquery, html, forms

HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#dropdown").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
```

When I run this in FireFox or Chrome, the drop down has the newly inserted blank option selected. When I run it in IE8, it still has Volvo selected. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/YFu2h/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Change it to this, and it'll work:

```
$("#theSelectId").prepend("<option value=''></option>").val('');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YFu2h/1/

It seems that IE only evaluates the `selected` attribute when it first encounters the `select`.

Comment: This will set the val to empty. Removing any selected items you my initially have

Comment: @HarryBosh - ...which is exactly what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure why your code is not working (maybe it has something to do with the fact that in IE, `selectedIndex` is readonly) but, doing this works in IE:

```
$("#dropdown").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
$("#dropdown")[0].options[0].selected = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$("#dropdown").prepend(new Option('', '', true, true));
$("#dropdown option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
$("#dropdown").prepend("<option value=''></option>");
$("#dropdown option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Using the first option is marginally quicker. The blank quotes mean blank value and blank text, so fill them in as you need. You don't need the selected attribute in the prepend now we are adding them afterwards. It's something to do with internet explorer not recognizing it being marked as selected as it has only just been created.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#id").prepend("<option value=' ' selected='selected'></option>");
```

prepend will add the option to top and **selected='selected'** will make it selected. As value=' ', so, it is blank value option.

Comment: Thanks David Angulo for asking, please check now.